# Why is an OTG not detected when a micro SD card is already inserted in the device?

Tags: sd-card, usb-on-the-go, internal-sd, pendrive

I have tried this on both Realme XT running Android 11 and Samsung Galaxy Tab S7+ running Android 12.
Whenever there's a micro SD card inserted and I attach a USB drive/SD card from my camera via OTG, it is not detected. But if I remove the micro SD card and try again with the OTG, it is detected.
I have realised that a micro SD card and another SD card/usb drive is not detected simultaneously on both my devices.

Am I missing something or is this a shortcoming of Android?

Comment: Mast likely the manufacturer has configured Micro SD-card and OTG device to use the same mount point and thus only one of both works.

Comment: That makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same issue, and I can tell you this is definitively not an Android issue, as I have devices that work fine, for instance, a Fire HD 10 running Android 9.

I think the issue is hardware related, as I have seen this problem with other devices, for instance an in-car entertainment system (Honda vehicle), where it tells you that you can't access the SD card while the USB port is in use, so I need to unplug my phone to use the SD card.

BTW, I just confirmed with Samsung support that in fact, you can't use both the SD card slot and the USB (otg) port at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought I was doing something wrong but now I know.